# Uploading images to Cloudinary with REMIX (Web Fetch API)

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, cloudinary, remix, remix.run

I am creating a `form` with Remix, and I want upload images to Cloudinary.

I have here a Vanilla JS form example showing how to use the Web Fetch API to send images to Cloudinary: https://codepen.io/team/Cloudinary/pen/QgpyOK <— I would like to "transform" or "adapt" this code to work with Remix. Does anybody could help me, please?

---

I will paste the code I am working with so far.

On this code I've added already the HTML code from the CodePen link above. I just need to know how to exactly add the JS code, after the `handleChange()` I believe.

On the form element `#fileElem` we see there the `onChange={handleFiles(this.files)}` and this is what triggers the upload. My problem now, and because I am also already creating a `post`, is that I don't know exactly how/where to add all the `handleFiles()` code from the codepen link above.

On the code below you'll find comment blocks where I explain what I was did.

```js
// import { isErrorResponse } from "@remix-run/react/data";
import { redirect, Form, useActionData, useTransition } from 'remix';
import { createPost } from '~/post';

export let action = async ({ request }) => {
  let formData = await request.formData();

  let title = formData.get('title');
  let slug = formData.get('slug');
  let markdown = formData.get('markdown');

  let errors = {};
  if (!title) errors.title = true;
  if (!slug) errors.slug = true;
  if (!markdown) errors.markdown = true;

  if (Object.keys(errors).length) {
    return errors;
  }

  await createPost({ title, slug, image, markdown });

  return redirect('/admin');
};

export default function NewPost() {
  let errors = useActionData();
  let transition = useTransition();
  let slug = '';

  const handleChange = (e, document) => {
    let text = e.target.value;
    // using regex and replace, let's convert spaces to dashes
    slug = text.replace(/\s/g, '-');
    // lets set the value of the slug text box to be our new slug in lowercase
    document.getElementById('slugInput').value = slug.toLowerCase();
  };

  // ATTEMPT - added bellow the JS code  from codepen !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  // ATTEMPT - added bellow the JS code  from codepen !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  // ATTEMPT - added bellow the JS code  from codepen !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

  const cloudName = 'demo';
  const unsignedUploadPreset = 'doc_codepen_example';

  var fileSelect = document.getElementById('fileSelect'),
    fileElem = document.getElementById('fileElem'),
    urlSelect = document.getElementById('urlSelect');

  fileSelect.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function (e) {
      if (fileElem) {
        fileElem.click();
      }
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
    },
    false
  );

  urlSelect.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function (e) {
      uploadFile('https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg');
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
    },
    false
  );

  // ************************ Drag and drop ***************** //
  function dragenter(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function dragover(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  dropbox = document.getElementById('dropbox');
  dropbox.addEventListener('dragenter', dragenter, false);
  dropbox.addEventListener('dragover', dragover, false);
  dropbox.addEventListener('drop', drop, false);

  function drop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var dt = e.dataTransfer;
    var files = dt.files;


    handleFiles(files);

  }

  // *********** Upload file to Cloudinary ******************** //
  function uploadFile(file) {
    var url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/upload`;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fd = new FormData();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    // Reset the upload progress bar
    document.getElementById('progress').style.width = 0;


    // Update progress (can be used to show progress indicator)
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
      var progress = Math.round((e.loaded * 100.0) / e.total);
      document.getElementById('progress').style.width = progress + '%';


      console.log(`fileuploadprogress data.loaded: ${e.loaded}, data.total: ${e.total}`);
    });


    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        // File uploaded successfully
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        // https://res.cloudinary.com/cloudName/image/upload/v1483481128/public_id.jpg
        var url = response.secure_url;
        // Create a thumbnail of the uploaded image, with 150px width
        var tokens = url.split('/');
        tokens.splice(-2, 0, 'w_150,c_scale');
        var img = new Image(); // HTML5 Constructor
        img.src = tokens.join('/');
        img.alt = response.public_id;
        document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(img);
      }
    };


    fd.append('upload_preset', unsignedUploadPreset);
    fd.append('tags', 'browser_upload'); // Optional - add tag for image admin in Cloudinary
    fd.append('file', file);
    xhr.send(fd);

  }

  // *********** Handle selected files ******************** //
  var handleFiles = function (files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      uploadFile(files[i]); // call the function to upload the file
    }
  };

  // ATTEMPT - end of JS code from codepen !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  // ATTEMPT - end of JS code from codepen !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  // ATTEMPT - end of JS code from codepen !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  // ATTEMPT - end of JS code from codepen !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  // ATTEMPT - end of JS code from codepen !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

  return (
    <Form method='post'>
      <p>
        <label htmlFor=''>
          Post Title: {errors?.title && <em>Title is required</em>}{' '}
          <input onChange={handleChange} type='text' name='title' />
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label htmlFor=''>
          {' '}
          Post Slug: {errors?.slug && <em>Slug is required</em>}
          <input placeholder={slug} id='slugInput' type='text' name='slug' />
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label htmlFor='markdown'>Markdown:</label>{' '}
        {errors?.markdown && <em>Markdown is required</em>}
        <br />
        <textarea name='markdown' id='' rows={20} cols={30} />
      </p>
      <p>
        <button type='submit'>
          {transition.submission ? 'Creating...' : 'Create Post'}
        </button>
      </p>

      {/* // ATTEMPT - added HTML form code from codepen !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  */}
      {/* // ATTEMPT - added HTML form code from codepen !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  */}
      {/* // ATTEMPT - added HTML form code from codepen !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  */}


      <div id='dropbox'>
        <h1>Client-Side Upload to Cloudinary with JavaScript</h1> Learn more in
        this blog post -{' '}
        <a href='https://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_upload_made_easy_from_browser_or_mobile_app_to_the_cloud'>
          Direct upload made easy from browser or mobile app to the cloud
        </a>
        <div className='form_line'>
          <h4>
            Upload multiple files by clicking the link below or by dragging and
            dropping images onto the dashed region
          </h4>
          <div className='form_controls'>
            <div className='upload_button_holder'>
              <input
                type='file'
                id='fileElem'
                multiple
                accept='image/*'
                style={{ display: 'none' }}
                onChange={handleFiles(this.files)}
              />
              <a href='#' id='fileSelect'>
                Select some files
              </a>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <a href='#' id='urlSelect'>
                URL Upload
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='progress-bar' id='progress-bar'>
          <div className='progress' id='progress'></div>
        </div>
        <div id='gallery' />
      </div>


      {/* // end of ATTEMPT  */}
      {/* // end of ATTEMPT  */}
      {/* // end of ATTEMPT  */}
    </Form>

  );
}
```

I've also found this post about this topic, but the code seems to be gone forever from the internet: https://twitter.com/remix_run/status/1494096161669464064?lang=en

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remix example was moved [here](https://github.com/remix-run/examples/tree/main/file-and-cloudinary-upload)

Comment: I was able to make it working. Thank you for the reply!